# node events.js:136 throw er; Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, npm

I am getting events.js:136 throw er; Unhandled 'error' event don't know how and why?
i have reinstalled the nodejs and mongodb as well but throwing same error.

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "bookstore",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "simple bookstore app",
"main": "app.js",
"devDependencies": {},
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "body-parser": "*",
    "mongoose": "*"
},
"author": "AveesP",
"license": "ISC"
```

}

**App.js code**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bookstore');
var db = mongoose.connection;
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.send('Hello world!');
});
app.listen(3000);
console.log('Running on port 3000...');
```

[image]

Comment: What do you expect from `var bodyParser = require();`?  Do you think `var bodyParser = require('body-parser')` might work better?

Comment: i have update the question showing "events.js:136 throw er; Unhandled 'error' event"

Comment: `require('')` is no better. You need to pass `require()` a value.

Comment: this is what i have written
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

Comment: Okay, so now you're getting a different error. Are you sure Mongo is running?

Answer (score 5):

Try to use the following commands to enlarge the number of handlers that actives the watcher (listener of application changes)

`sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288`
`sudo sysctl -p --system`

Comment: I get this error when I run "docpress s" , maybe the docpress cannot watch so many files

Comment: Thanks @andhdo. It works for me. Why I have to use these commands ?

Answer (score 0):

I have got that root cause.. i have not made any database using mongodb its a connection error..

thanks Mark for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in port

```
app.listen(8080);
```

try these code

```
  var http = require('http');
 //create a server object:
  http.createServer(function (req, res) {
 res.write('Hello World!'); //write a response to the client
 res.end(); //end the response
}).listen(8080); //the server object listens on port 8080
```